# ¿ Como modificar datos en un array en java?

Tags: java, menú

Tengo un código es un menú de registros de jugadores donde debo pedir el Número, Nombre, Edad y Posición. Una de las opciones del menú es modificar la posición de un jugador que ya esta registrado, ¿alguna idea de como?.

El `case 4` es la opción de **Modificar** la posición (Según debe ser bastante similar al case 3 pero no puedo hacer que haga eso).

Código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int ap= -1,i,op,p,buscarnum,buscar ;
    boolean existe=false;
    boolean encontrar=false;
    String aux = "";
    int []Numero=new int[5];
    String[] Nombre=new String[5];
    int[]Edad=new int[5];
    String[] Posicion=new String[5];
    do
    {
        op=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Menu\n1.-Registro del jugador\n2.-Consulta General\n3.-Busqueda por Numero de Jugador\n4.-Modificar La Posicion\n5.-Eliminar\n6.-Salida"));
        switch(op)
        {
        case 1: 
        if(ap!=4)   
        {
          encontrar=false;
          buscarnum=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Dame Numero de Jugador"));
          for(i=0;i<=ap;i++)
          {
              if(buscarnum==Numero[ap])
                  encontrar=true;
          }//for
          if(encontrar==false)
          {
              ap++;

              Numero[ap]=buscarnum;
              Nombre[ap]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Dame Nombre de Jugador");
              Edad[ap]=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Dame Edad de Jugador"));
              p=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Dame la Posicion\n1.-Delantero\n2.-Portero\n3.-Defensa\n4.-MedioCampista"));
              if(p==1)
                  Posicion[ap]="Delantero";
              if(p==2)
                  Posicion[ap]="Portero";
              if(p==3)
                  Posicion[ap]="Defensa";
              if(p==4)
                  Posicion[ap]="MedioCampista";

          }//if
          else
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El numero de jugador ya existe");

        }
          else
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Hay Espacio");
        break;
        case 2: if(ap!=-1)
        {
            aux="";
            for(i=0;i<=ap;i++)
            {
                aux=aux+"\nNumero de Jugador: "+Numero[i]+ "\nNombre del Jugador: " +Nombre[i]+"\nEdad Del Jugador: " +Edad[i]+"\nPosicion del Jugador: " +Posicion[i]+ "\n\n";

            }//for
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Consulta General\n\n "+aux );

        }//if
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No hay Datos");
        break;
        case 3: 
        if(ap!=-1)
        {
           existe=false;
        buscar=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Dame Numero a Buscar"));


        for(i=0;i<=ap;i++)
        {
            if(buscar==(Numero[i]))
            {
                existe=true;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\nNumero de Jugador: "+Numero[i]+"\n Nombre del Jugador: "+Nombre[i]+"\nEdad del Jugador: "+Edad[i]+"\nPosicion del Jugador: "+Posicion[i]+"\n\n");
            }//if
        }//for
        if(existe==false)

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El numero " +buscar+ " No Existe");        
        }
        else

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No hay Datos");

        break;
        case 4: 

            Break;
        case 5 : if(ap!=-1)
        {
            ap--;
        }
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No hay Registros");
            break;  
        }//switch

    }while(op!=6);//while
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fin del Programa");
}//main
```

Comment: Para poner el código, edita la pregunta y agregale 4 espacios en blanco al principo de cada línea de código :)

Comment: Pues ya puse el código, No se si se ve bien.Gracias

Comment: O mejor aún, selecciona el código y preciona `CTRL+k`

Comment: ¿Has intentando algo concreto? Si he entendido bien, sólo tendrías que coger el objeto del array, mostrar los datos de este objeto al usuario para que pueda editarlos y actualizar los datos en el objeto.

Answer (score 1):

puede ser con esto.

```
nombre=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nombre de jugador al que se le cambia la posición");
nuevapos=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la nueva posicion"));

for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
if(Nombre[i].equals(nombre))
    Posicion[i]=nuevapos;
}
```